If Clutch fork moves smoothly when clutch pedal is pressed, can the slave and/or master cylinder be ruled out as the problem?
For car that will not go into gear with a running engine.
When a friend presses the clutch, the slave cylinder appears to be working normally. The clutch fork moves smoothly.
Does this mean essentially that the slave and master cylinder are functioning properly, and the problem is likely with the clutch itself, possibly the throw out bearing or something else?
Or is it still possible either the slave or master are still malfunctioning in some less detectable way that is preventing the ability to shift into gear?
Can I rule those two out in favor of another problem, in other words?
No visible leaks in either slave or master. Fluid level is stable.
SCION tC 05, 147k miles

If your fluid is old you may not be getting complete extension. If you bleed the clutch hydraulic system and it still has problems going into gear then the clutch hydraulics are not the problem.

It is possible that either master or slave cylinders have worn out pistons, essentially "leaking into themselves" and not developing enough pressure to fully push the fork in. From my experience, it is more common with master cylinder, however (at least on my vehicles) the slave is easier to replace.
